# Clone a hard drive with ubuntu live?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, hardware-failure, sata

My desktop hard drive is failing and I have to clone windows 8 and all my files asap! Was thinking that I could boot into ubuntu live and copy my failing drive to an external drive then swap it out with the new drive and copy files back to the new drive. Not sure if it will work or not.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). You can put it on a USB stick or CD, and run from there. Keep the old disk and leave it until you're sure everything is copied over. Youtube has some videos showing how it works. It looks terrible, but it works and does what you need.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-image-your-drives-for-free-with-clonezilla/